# Can't add Windows Server 2019 as AD to domain replica error

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

**Context:**
I've got a Windows domain with a Windows 2016 functional level.
Currently all the ADs (three) are based on Windows Server 2016 and up to date.

**Problem:**
I want to had a Windows Server 2019 as AD to the domain. I can join the domain but I can't promote the server as AD. The wizard, when you fill up the domain, pops out a red notification which tells me that there is a replica error.

[image]

**Checked:**
Based on my research I've checked that I have the `SYSVOL Share` as a `msDFSR-ContentSet`.
Based on `repadmin /replsum` everything is ok

Comment: You know what would be helpful? The actual error message.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following powershell commands: (Get-ADForest).ForestMode and (Get-ADDomain).DomainMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@eKKiM](https://serverfault.com/a/996784/212173) said the forest functional level was lower than the domain functional level.

Fixed with the command : `Set-ADForestMode -ForestMode Windows2016Forest`

Answer (score 3):

As stated in your post your domain is probably in the Windows Server 2016 Domain Functional Level. However your Forest functional level might be lower.

Verify your domain functional level via PowerShell:

```
(Get-ADDomain).DomainMode
```

Verify your forestfunctional level via PowerShell:

```
(Get-ADForest).ForestMode
```

Beware before upgrading your domain or forest functional level. It is **almost** impossible to roll back this operation!